# How can I handle text in AS3 simply?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, text

I feel like every time I need to use TextField or anything else related in AS3, it becomes a giant mess of code just for a few lines.

I have tried using css as well for text but have encountered some issues where it isn't rendered the same on different servers/clients.

Are there any text handling libraries that I don't know of or some other way to manage text in AS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create custom GUI components to encapsulate the giant mess of code and then provide a simple interface for doing what you want. You could either extend `TextField`, or, favoring composition over inheritance, your custom class could contain a `TextField`.

Comment: That what I was going to do if I found no other solution. Thanks though :)

Comment: This is what I ended up doing in a project that had many dynamically created GUI widgets. A simple EasyTextField class that managed its own TextFormat and had a constructor with many default arguments in order of decreasing priority did wonders for my code's tidiness.

Answer (score 0):

To be totally honest Flash doesn't support fonts very well, actually it's appalling. So I save myself a *lot* of time and just use the Flash IDE to create a textfield, embed the fonts, enclose it within a MovieClip that's then classed up and export it as a SWC and link it into my compiler as a library. Simples.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: [F*CSS](http://fcss.flashartofwar.com/)